# How can I emit the entire value of a text input?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

MyComponent.vue:

```html
<BaseInput
    id="name"
    v-model:modelValue="user.name"
    type="text"
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    placeholder="Name"
/>
```

BaseInput.vue:

```html
<template>
<input
    :id="id"
    class="peer absolute block w-full border-0 bg-transparent p-0 px-3 text-base text-purple-500 placeholder-orange-500 transition-all duration-100 ease-in-out focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm"
    :class="inputHasValue ? 'top-5' : 'top-3'"
    :type="type"
    :name="name"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :value="value"
    @input="(event) => $emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)"
    @focus="handleInputFocus"
    @keyup="handleInputKeyup"
/>
...
</template>


<script>
...
emits: ['update:modelValue'],
...
</script>
```

Things are kind of working here. When I type into my input, I can see that the v-model is being populated in `MyComponent.vue`:

```
user:Reactive
   name:"d"
```

The problem I'm seeing is the value is being replaced by whatever I type last. For example, if I entered the text "abcd" only "d" would show in the v-model.

How can I emit the entire value so that "abcd" shows?

```
user:Reactive
   name:"abcd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<input>` has no model. It only binds its `value` property to a local `value` ref, which likely is initially blank or `null`, and that ref never gets updated.

The `input`-event emits the current value of the `<input>` element with the newly entered character appended to it. Since the current value is always blank in this case, the event data only contains the new character.

But it looks like the component isn't designed to modify the `value` ref based on what is being emitted (e.g., filtering out characters), so it doesn't need to keep a local copy of it.

Removing the unnecessary `value` ref and binding the `<input>`'s `value` directly to `modelValue` would resolve the issue:

```html
<!-- <input :value="value"> --> ❌

<input :value="modelValue"> ✅
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-input-wrapper-dwt2s8?file=src/components/BaseInput.vue)

*Side note:* `v-model:modelValue` can be simplified to `v-model` because `"modelValue"` is the default binding argument:

```html
<BaseInput v-model:modelValue="user.name" />
<!-- is the same as: -->
<BaseInput v-model="user.name" />
```